# What is the use of java.util.spi package?

Tags: java, java-8, package, java-6

I saw `java.util.spi` package and it seems like there are some classes suffixed with `Name`, `Data`, `Control` and `Service Providers`. Some of the classes where new(`Since 1.8`) and some where exist from `Java 1.6`. I don't find much resources to understand the usage of this `spi` package.

Is there anyone who uses these classes in `spi` package? If so could you please let me know what exactly these classes are used for?

Comment: Any reason for tagging java-8?

Comment: Yes, some classes are implemented newly in this package on Java 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This package contains `SPI` providers for some classes in `java.util` package. SPI stands for `Service Provider Interface` and it's a standard Java way to plugin additional functionality as a service discovery mechanism - You can read more about it here [SPI basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html).
Some good details are also available under this question: [difference-between-spi-and-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954372/difference-between-spi-and-api)