# Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: mysql, jdbc

This is the Warning im getting in console, Im confused with this warning:

```
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. 
This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'.
The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading 
of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
```

Comment: why is _this_ Q closed as duplicate? the linked Q is newer, has less score and answers, has worse wording etc

Answer (score 114):

I resolved this problem by change `application.properties` of

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

to

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 31):

According [Changes in the Connector/J API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) "The name of the class that implements java.sql.Driver in MySQL Connector/J has changed from **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** to **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver**. The old class name has been deprecated."

This means that you just need to change the name of the driver:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

to

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: Sonar gives warning for Class.forName stating remove the use dynamic class loading.

Answer (score 27):

If you're using Hibernate then change in your "hibernate.cfg.xml" the following:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

To:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

That should do :)

Answer (score 9):

Change driver property in your ORM config file from

```
 <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
```

to

```
<property name="driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
```

This will resolve the warning :-)

Answer (score 9):

The sentence "Loading class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' " is clear. You should use the newer driver, like this:

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

And in mysql-connector-java-8.0.17. You would find that Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver doesn't provide service any more. (You also can found the warning came from here.)

```java
public class Driver extends com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver {
    public Driver() throws SQLException {
    }

    static {
        System.err.println("Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.");
    }
}
```

The sentence 'The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.' It mean that write code like this is ok:

```java
//Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai","root","root");
```

Due to SPI, driver is automatically registered. How does it work? You can find this from java.sql.DriverManager:

```java
private static void ensureDriversInitialized() {
                          ...
    ServiceLoader<Driver> loadedDrivers = ServiceLoader.load(Driver.class);
                          ...
}
```

And in your mysql-connector-java-XXX.jar, you also can find the file 'java.sql.Driver' in the META-INF\services. The file as follows:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

When you run DriverManager.getConnection(), the static block also start running. So driver can be automatically registered with file 'java.sql.Driver'.

And more about SPI -> [Difference between SPI and API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954372/difference-between-spi-and-api).

Answer (score 5):

This is beacuse the version of mysql to be connected is lower than the version of the mysql driver.
Many people say that com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is changed to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver , although this does not solve the problem, but it should also attract attention.

Comment: This solved it for me. Although in my case, the other error messages did say 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc'

Answer (score 4):

Please remove existing **spring.datasource.driver-class-name** property in the **application.properties** file and add the below property.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
        // broken Java implementations
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with detailed explanation? This will be very useful to understand your idea. Thank you!

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance() 
In this code  .newInstance() method is wire beetween broken implementation.
This is link is more helpful [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html]  @vezunchik

Answer (score 3):

Changed my **application.conf** file as below. It solved the problem.

**Before Change:**

```
slick {
  dbs {
    default {
      profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
      db {
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
        user = "root"
        password = "root"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**After Change:**

```
slick {
  dbs {
    default {
      profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
      db {
        **driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"**
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
        user = "root"
        password = "root"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I had a line 
  **Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");**
after removing this line code works fine 
if you have any line for loading "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" remove it, it doesn't require any more

Answer (score 2):

By changing the driver name from "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" to "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" will solve this problem.

In case of simple JDBC connection :
`Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");`

In case of hibernate :
`<property name="driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Eclipse and defined MySql connection pool in META_INF/context.xml. Part of its content is:

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="..." 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    ... />
</Context>
```

When I changed the line starting with "driverClassName" as follows, problem is gone.

```
driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
```

Comment: Reproduced the same for Intellij IDEA 2020.2. This suggestion is relevant, because properties file was correct.

Answer (score 2):

This warning also appears if you are using the **log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter** library directly.

However there is a config to choose the correct driver yourself. Put this in your `application.properties`:

```
log4jdbc.drivers=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
log4jdbc.auto.load.popular.drivers=false
```

See documentation on [Github](https://github.com/candrews/log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter)

Answer (score 2):

I only changed this line of code `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` to `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");`. I see some other people going to application.properties and adding a few things. For me this is the best and fastest way but I also respect other people's answer.

Comment: Where is that code? Where did you change it?

Answer (score 2):

remove line on configuration your config file **application.properties**

[image]

Because spring say:  The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

Comment: Huh, this is exactly what I tried before searching for help on the web, but in that case it failed to connect to DB with "No driver found" or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

In case of using a configuration based on a YML file, the following will be the property that needs to be adjusted inside the given file:

`*driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver*`

Answer (score 1):

The driver is automatically registered via SPI and manual loading of the driver class is usually unnecessary. Just change "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

Answer (score 1):

If seeing this message in Hive with new MySQL connector `8.x` (MySQL metastore)

open `hive-site.xml` and change:

```
   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
      <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
   </property>
```

to

```
   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</value>
      <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
   </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:
        org.springframework.boot 2.0.5.RELEASE

Rather: org.springframework.boot 2.1.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

in my experience. I was using jsp for web. at that time I use mysql 5 and mysql connecter jar 8. So due to the version problem I face this kind of problem. I solve by replace the mysql connector jar file the exact version mysql.

Answer (score 0):

working example:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_db_name?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "root");
```

call like this it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There important changes to the Connector/J API going from version 5.1 to 8.0. You might need to adjust your API calls accordingly if the version you are using falls above 5.1.

please visit MySQL on the following link for more information https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

just delete this part `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` from your code

because the machine is throwing a warning that

> The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary."

meaning that no need to include it beacuse the driver is automatically registered for you by default.

Comment: then it says No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in your `application.properties`:

`spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`,

you can get rid of the error by removing that line.

Answer (score 0):

Now you database connection create according to the this format.

```
public void Connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/JavaCRUD","root","");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Edit this code like this.

```
    public void Connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/JavaCRUD","root","");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //it's old the mysql driver
```

**changes old to new driver
-------------------------**

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); //it's new the mysql driver and paste same place and resolved your problem
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Where did you change it? Where did you find this code?