# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'userinfo'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I clearly have a database named userinfo with a table named userName. I am using XAMPP

```
public class DatabaseHelper {
    private static final String dbName = "userinfo";
    Connection connection;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Timestamp date;

public  Connection getConnection(){

        String dbName = "userinfo";
    String userName="root";
    String password="12345678";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+dbName,userName,password);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    createUsersTable();
    return connection;

}

public void createUsersTable() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+dbName);
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users"
                    + "(Id          INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY        AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + " Firstname   TEXT                    NOT NULL,"
                    + " Lastname        TEXT                    NOT NULL,"
                    + " Username        TEXT                    NOT NULL,"
                    + " Password        TEXT                    NOT NULL,"
                    + " TotalAmount DOUBLE                  NOT NULL,"
                    + " StockAmount DOUBLE                  NOT NULL,"
                    + " Email       TEXT                    NOT NULL" + ");";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("User table creation successful");
    }
```

The error I am getting :
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.131
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'userinfo'

undate: this is the error i am getting now Mar 07, 2020 2:58:56 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.131
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032739/loading-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-this-is-deprecated-the-new-driver-class

Comment: 1)  Show us the complete stacktrace so that we can understand where you are getting the error.  2) You say "I clearly have a database named userinfo with a table named userName".  Please explain why you are so sure about this ... in the face of your program saying this is not the case.

Comment: Mar 07, 2020 3:04:37 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.131
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0):

This question is incomplete, so we can't give you a definitive answer.  I have commented to point out the extra information that you need to provide .... if you want a complete answer / solution.

Here are some initial problems that you need to fix.

1. These statements are unnecessary and should be removed:

   ```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
   ```

   It has not been necessary since Java 6 and JDBC 4.0 compliant drivers for MySQL were released.  Roughly 2007!  You **only** need to use `DriverManager.getConnection`.

   Why does this matter?  Well, the driver class name is database and driver **version** dependent.  If you hardwire a driver classname into your code, it is liable to break<sup>1</sup>.  (Also, an unnecessary `Class.forName` call is inefficient.)
2. Your code is not using the account name and password.  You will be connecting to the database with no account name and no password.  Depending on the way that the MySQL access control has been configured, this *might* cause it to say that a particular database does not exist.  (Possibly ... though I doubt it.)
3. Your code is managing the connection incorrectly:

   - Your `getConnection` calls `DriverManager.getConnection` and assigns the result to `connection`.
   - Then it calls `createUserTable` ... which calls `DriverManager.getConnection` again, and assigns it to the same `connection` variable.
   - Then `createUserTable` executes some SQL and **closes `connection`**.
   - As a result, your `getConnection` will ultimately return a `Connection` that has been closed.

   The `createUserTable` should not be calling `DriverManager.getConnection`, and it should not be closing `connection`.
4. Calling `System.exit` deep in your code is generally a bad idea.  It is better to allow the exception to propagate so that something further up can deal with it.

---

<sup>1 - This is not a theoretical problem.  The driver class name **did** change between MySQL Connector/J 5.x and MySQL Connector/J 8.0.</sup>

Comment: This is what i am getting now: Mar 07, 2020 2:58:56 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.131
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: this is what i get if i leave the password blank                                                      
 Mar 07, 2020 3:01:14 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.131
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: And rightly so.  It would be crazy if the database allowed you to connect as "root" with no password.  You need to use the correct account name and the correct password, and actually supply them when you try to connect.  Find out from the DB administrator what they should be.