# Cannot Invoke java.sql.Connecton.preparestatement(String) because con is null

Tags: netbeans

> I keep having errors says that Cannot Invoke java.sql.Connecton.preparestatement(String) because con is null

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class myConnection {

```
 static Connection getConnection(){
     Connection con = null;
     try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = (Connection) java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/summative", "root", "");
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        
    }
return con;
   }
```

}

> And this is the error
> [Photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyg4v.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using an ancient driver your class name is not valid anymore. You should use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

See also also [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) or [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032739/loading-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-this-is-deprecated-the-new-driver-class).