# Java pluginable application how does consumer load interface?

Tags: java, plugins, interface, loading

I'm creating a small hobby Java task/todo application. I want to be able to write plugins for it, which will be stored in a directory somewhere, probably in a `plugins` directory next to the `myapplication.jar`.

I have some idea on how to load these plugins, and I want to write interfaces which the plugin creator can use, like `SomeActionInterface`, when implemented allows the plugin to add functionality to `SomeAction`.

My question is, where does that `SomeActionInterface` go, and how would the plugin creator access said interface?

Does the interface go in the main `myapplication.jar` which the user should have loaded on their classpath, or does it go in a separate `myapplication-plugininterfaces.jar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would expose [SPI and API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2956803/1602555) that the plugin authors can use to implement their code. Normally these classes are packaged as a separate JAR, this allows to have a minimal dependency to build a plugin.

There are some good examples of plugin architecture that you can explore:

- JDBC exposes [`java.sql.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) and relate classes so the database projects can implement drivers for Java.
- [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) handles new logger framework bindings as plugins. There are [`slf4-api` and `slf4j-ext` dependencies](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=logging-log4j2.git;a=blob;f=pom.xml;h=b00371440e227af1ddda434e8be801d635ccda27;hb=HEAD#l266) that are used to implement a plugin.

Comment: And this API jar should also be included in the main project right? To be able to call the interfaced plugins.

Comment: @Oreborous If you use Maven or any other build system that allows for modules you usually end up with `api`, `application` and possibly a `common` module shared between `api`, `application`. `application` depends on `api` but not the other way. You want to make `api` a separate module and keep it small e.g. don't add 3rd party libraries there if you can avoid it.